# Corner points from an image to redraw the outline it in Matlab or Python

Tags: python, image, matlab, image-processing

I have one image. I want to get the coordinates in order so that the image can be redrawn. The image may be complex. I want to get sampled corner coordinates to redraw the outline of the image.

**Attempt 1: `corner` function**

I tried to detect the corner using `corner()` in matlab but it is not giving exact point. The corners are lying outside. The original image is attached below.

[image: asd]

My code for corner detection is:

```
It=rgb2gray(I);
Itt=im2bw(It);
Itt1=corner(Itt);
imshow(Itt);
hold on
plot(Itt1(:,1), Itt2(:,2), 'r*');
```

The output of corner detection is attached below:

[image]

**Problem with `corner`:** If you zoom the image, you will find that the some corners don't lie on boundaries. So, please suggest some efficient and good working method.

**Attempt 2: `bwtraceboundaries`**

I also tried using `bwtraceboundaries` and corners to order the corner in terms of `bwtraceboundaries` output but the corner is not being exactly detected.

**Question:** Can you please suggest how can I detect the corner or is there any other method to extract the sampled corner points from the image so that the outline can be redrawn?

Comment: It is unclear what you want. The coordinates of what exactly?

Comment: The coordinates(say corner) so that the image can be redrawn connecting those coordinates through lines.

Comment: So you want every corner point of that white area? why does `bwtraceboundaries` not work? can you show us?

Comment: The corner points through corner detection algorithms won't be in order. I want the corners in order so that I can just connect them through lines.

Comment: Show a [mcve] please

Comment: I have attached the output of corner detection. Please check.

Comment: Code, show code. Also try `bwperim`

Comment: bwperim is also not working as it is merging two different objects. So, I can't use it.

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`bwboundaries`](https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) to achieve what you want. It returns all the sorted boundary positions as a cell array:

```matlab
B = bwboundaries(Itt);
imshow(Itt);
hold on
B = B{2}; % select the desired boundary (the second in this case)
plot(B(:,2), B(:,1), 'b-'); % draw a connected line
```

[image]

If you want to obtain only the corner points, you can filter them out manually by checking if the point lies in the middle of the next and previous point as follows:

```matlab
iBremove = []; % redundant indexes in B
for k=2:length(B)-1 % loop over all the points, except the first and last one
  Bk = (B(k-1, :) + B(k+1, :))/2; % interpolate the previous and next point
  if all(Bk == B(k, :)) % check if point k is redundant
    iBremove = [iBremove k]; % add to the list of indexes to remove
  end
end
B(iBremove, :) = []; % remove the redundant points out of B

plot(B(:,2), B(:,1), 'r*-'); % draw a connected line
```

[image]

Comment: Nice approach. I tried this. But bwboundaries is storing all the pixels. I want the corner pixels only. For example, if it's a rectangle I want only four points.